# Problem in Using fonticon at openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, style

I'm developing an application using [openlayers 3.11.2](http://openlayers.org/). I have a point layer. I want to style this layer using font-icon base of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809479/use-semantic-ui-or-font-awesome-icons-as-markers-in-openlayers3). When I use `FontAwesome` fonticon, It work correctyl, But when I use My `fonticon`, It dose not work correctyl.

**Note**:
I created my fontIcon at [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select).

**Where is the problem**?

**Edit**:
I define the style as follow:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '\e900',
    font: 'normal 18px MyFontIcon',
    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white',
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I updated it man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you work with font, it's necessary to know if your code work in unicode or not. Today UTF8 is a standard (unicode) codepage.

In this situation, you need use **`\u`** before the code and not just **`\`**

For read easiest, you can set a dict in specific javascript file (or directly in your code) for exemple:

my_unicode_font.js

```
var Icon = {
    Ok : "\uf000",
    Bad : "\uf001",
    Search : "\uf002",
    // and others in your webfont.ttf (change with corresponding utf8 code)
    }
```

in file.htm

```
<html>

   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="my_unicode_font.js" ></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      .......
   </body>
</html>
```

and in your script part

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: Icon.Ok, // my font caracter
    font: 'normal 18px MyFontIcon',
    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white',
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I want to use fonticon dynamically. My features have an code as : feature1->001, feature2->002, and etc. But when I want to use `"\uf" + feature.get("code")` it error, how Can i fix this error?

Comment: Please, create new question. An validate response if it fix your problem

Comment: @mortezamalvandi you can try in this case `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(feature.get("code")))` if your code is in hexa, use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(feature.get("code"), 16))`

Answer (score 1):

Set `\ue900` to text as follow:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '\ue900',
    font: 'normal 18px MyFontIcon',
    textBaseline: 'Bottom',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'white',
    })
  })
});
```

I don't know why it worked correctly with this small change, But I think `\u` define `unicode`.

Comment: You might want to explain why, rather than just copying the answer to the linked question on SE?

Comment: I only solve the #morteza malvandi's problem

Comment: @MohammadRezaHasanzadeh just add part of change and explain it's more easy to undertand. I remove non usefull

Comment: I would also like to see a more detailed explanation about the `\u` part. Yes, it is unicode, more specifically it is the unicode escape sequence in JS. I would strongly recommend removing the part "I don't know why it worked", researching the phenomenon you are not familiar with, and giving a decent answer. A good starting point can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals).

Comment: I want to use fonticon dynamically. My features have an code as : feature1->001, feature2->002, and etc. But when I want to use "\uf" + feature.get("code") it error, how Can i fix this error?

Comment: @mortezamalvandi This is an other question. You need create a new question